# Unable to connect from MySQL Workbench to server (System error 61)

Tags: mysql, connection

**MySQL error:**

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at 12.34.567.890:3306 with user jsdbadmin

Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61
```

**Using:**

Plesk, SuSE vServer, fresh installation: completly new about an half year ago.

**Software:**

Trying to connect via MySQL Workbench, current version.

**Hostname**: 12.34.567.890 (modified for privacy), also tried with domain
**Port**: 3306
**Username**: My DB user name, as specified in Plesk when DB was created.
**Password**: ***************************
**Default Schema**: feeds

Tried TCP/IP, TC/IP over ssh.

**Searched online:**

These settings are **not** the problem:

```
#skip-networking
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Both already commented out.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a Firewall blocking the connection ?

You can test by telneting to the mysql port.

you also need to allow the ip/user combos that are allowed to connect

e.g.
to add a new user

```
GRANT ALL ON jsdbadmin.* TO remoteadmuser@'12.34.567.890' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

or
to grant access to a specific ip

```
update db set Host='12.34.567.890' where Db='yourdatabase';
update user set Host='12.34.567.890' where user='jsdbadmin';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible (really annoying) error is that the server's public ssh keys have changed since your last login or that you've never logged in to that server using SSH and therefore you must manually approve them.

To solve this:

1. `$ nano ~/.ssh/known_hosts`
2. Remove old server keys from the file. Save & exit.
3. Connect to the server manually (ie. from terminal) and approve saving the new keys
4. After successful login from terminal, retry the mysql connection over ssh.

That worked for me...